# Overlaying two divs over another

Tags: html, css

I'd like to overlay two icons over another div and also align them to the right.

The relevant code at the moment can be summarized as

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">icon1</div>
  <div class="icon">icon2</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative
}

.icon {
  position: absolute
  right: 0px
}
```

As it stands, the icons align to the right over the div, but also overlap over one another. How would I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's the difference between overlay and overlap?

Comment: I meant the same thing. At the moment my code has both icons overlap the container, but they occupy the exact same space (the top right corner). I'd like them to sit side to side while also occupying the top right corner.

Comment: CSS Flex is your friend: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Both icons are positioned with the same location (right: 0px) so I would expect them to overlap.

Comment: Absolute positioning takes elements out of the normal document flow, which means, as I like to phrase it, elements are no longer able to "see" other elements. This is why they stack. When an element IS IN the NORMAL document flow, they will "see" each other. Meaning, they will push each other around based on their properties and the properties of other elements that can influence them - i.e. parent, child, sibling elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this might be the result you're looking for ?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">icon1</div>
  <div class="icon">icon2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, this is what i was trying to accomplish.